# Move code between Git Repositories

Tags: git, version-control

I have a Git repository with multiple branches. I'm looking to take certain folders from one of the branches and create a new repository with just those folders. What's the best way to do this while keeping my history for those folders intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For certain definition of 'intact', you can create a history of commits which only contains a given folder by using [`git filter-branch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-filter-branch) with the `--subdirectory-filter` option.

See this previous SO question: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: This is also described in Github help: http://help.github.com/split-a-subpath-into-a-new-repo/

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest way I can think of is to clone the existing repository and just delete all the folders you don't want to keep in the new repo.